# Go to a specific Tab from Chrome's Task Manager

Tags: google-chrome

When I open Task Manager of Google Chrome, I can see all my tabs listed in the Task column. Is there a way to go to a tab shown in the Task column? I am looking for something similar to the "Switch To" or "Bring to Front" in Windows Task Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question, Google Chrome already does what you want.
Go to the Task Manager, double-click a tab e voila!

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that double-click would do that. Now, if there was a way to go to the last tab I was on (after double-clicking), it would be perfect.

Comment: @unubar I got you covered! CTRL + 9 will do just it! From the [Chrome keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en-GB)

Comment: thanks. CTRL+9 goes to the last tab. I actually meant, the "previous" tab that I was on. Sorry about the incorrect word usage.

Comment: For that , you'd really need to have only one Chrome window open, and be using an extension that provides MRU tab switching functionality.